# How to properly catch errors when running scripts on buffers?

Tags: buffers

I am trying to write a function to lint buffers in neovim. It seems that the usual recommendation for achieving such a thing is to run the command over the entire range (ie `%!lint`). This is however, problematic if the file is not properly formatted. In (neo)vim's current behaviour, it appears that even stderr output from the lint program will replace the entire buffer.

I have attempted to fix this by running the lint command separately and checking for shell errors, like so:

```
" example usage:
" :call RunBuf("python -m json.tool")
function! RunBuf(cmd) abort
  redir => output
  silent execute ":w !" . a:cmd
  redir END
  if v:shell_error
    echo output
    return
  endif
  let pos = getcurpos()
  execute "%!" . a:cmd
  call setpos('.', pos)
endfunction
```

This is still not optimal as the lint command needs to be executed twice. I am thinking if there is a way to replace the entire buffer with `output`, or if there's a simpler way of achieving the same?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D Ben Knoble's [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/26916/20542) looks promising, but I hated the idea of using temporary files. After some digging, I found another way to achieve the desired behaviour, largely stolen from the [dart vim plugin fmt iimplementation](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-vim-plugin/blob/master/autoload/dart.vim#L28):

```
function! RunBuf(cmd) abort
  let buffer_content = getline(1, '$')
  let lines = systemlist(a:cmd, join(buffer_content, "\n"))
  if v:shell_error
    echo join(lines, "\n")
    return
  endif
  silent keepjumps call setline(1, lines)
  if line('$') > len(lines)
    silent keepjumps execute string(len(lines)+1).',$ delete'
  endif
endfunction
```

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to

- run the linter on the file and shove the output in a temporary file (relevant docs: `:range!`, `:make`, `shell`, `shellredir`, `shellcmdflag`, `shellpipe`, `tempname()`)
- if no error, simply replace everything with that file: `:%delete | execute 'read' tempfile | 0delete`
- delete the tempfile (`:call delete(tempfile)`)

I think this would look like (but I haven't tested it yet):

```
function RunBuf(cmd) abort
  let temp = tempname()
  silent execute 'write !' cmd &shellredir temp
  if v:shell_error is# 0
    %delete
    execute '1read' temp
    1delete
  endif
  call delete(temp)
  redraw!
endfunction
```

However, you might be better off integrating with something like ALE (which, AFAIK, handles all this nonsense for you) or another linter plugin.

---

I think the reason stderr is usually included is because `shellpipe` and `shellredir` are set to include stderr when the `shell` supports it.

Comment: Note that this is most of what `:range!` does, just with the extra error checking